# flutter question: why is this giving me a bunch or errors? below is my code and errors

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

errors
- Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.dart(uri_does_not_exist

- The name 'FirebaseUser' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
  Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'FirebaseUser'.dart(non_type_as_type_argument)

code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

abstract class BaseAuth {
  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password);

  Future<String> signUp(String email, String password);

  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser();

  Future<void> sendEmailVerification();

  Future<void> signOut();

  Future<bool> isEmailVerified();
}

class Authen implements BaseAuth {
  final Auth _firebaseAuth = Auth.instance;

  Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }

  Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult result = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

  Future<void> sendEmailVerification() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    user.sendEmailVerification();
  }

  Future<bool> isEmailVerified() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user.isEmailVerified;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the first error because the package wasn't properly installed. You can try a few things:

1. `flutter packages get` (to use the packages in pubspec.yaml)
2. restarting your IDE
3. `flutter clean` and then `flutter run` (clears build cache)
4. `flutter packages pub cache repair` (pub cache might be corrupted)

The second error will resolve itself once the package is correctly installed. Because 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' doesn't exist, you can't use any classes from that package. FirebaseUser is a class in the firebase_auth package.

Comment: You can add to your answer to check if the package is declared in pubspec.yaml